# Export of accessor columns in django tables2 not working

Tags: django-tables2

Table export using django tables2 producing only the model data but not accessor columns.

Below are my table and view configurations. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Table**

```
class AgreementPeopleTable(tables.Table):

    export_formats = ['csv', 'xls']
    #title = tables.Column(linkify=True)
    full_name = tables.Column(accessor='employement_episode.contact.full_name', verbose_name='Full Name')
    start = tables.Column(accessor='employement_episode.start_date')
    end = tables.Column(accessor='employement_episode.end_date')
    role = tables.Column(accessor='employement_episode.contact.role_name',verbose_name='Role')
    organization = tables.Column(accessor='employement_episode.organization.organization_name',verbose_name='Organization')
    title = tables.Column(accessor='agreement.title')
    status = tables.Column(accessor='agreement.status')

    class Meta:
        model = Agreement_People
        exclude = ('agreement_people_id', 'employement_episode','agreement')
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap4.html'
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-hover'}
```

**View**

```
class AgreementPeopleListView(ExportMixin, tables.SingleTableView, generic.ListView):
    model = Agreement_People
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AgreementPeopleListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        agreementpeople = Agreement_People.objects.all()
        form = AgreementPeopleForm(self.request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            #print("date signed db value", date_signed)
            if form.cleaned_data["title"]:
                agreementpeople = agreementpeople.filter(agreement__title__icontains=form.cleaned_data["title"])


        table = AgreementPeopleTable(agreementpeople.order_by('pk'))
        RequestConfig(self.request, paginate={'per_page': 4}).configure(table)
        context['table'] = table
        context['form'] = AgreementPeopleForm()
        return context
```

**Excel output**

```
Note: Accessor columns are not coming excel output, only columns defined in model are retrieved.
```

ModelCol1    ModelCol2  ModelCol3

1               XYZ       PQR

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I just [added a test](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/commit/9caf34e20e0377f89ad02bac6ac813abd1e38191) to the django-tables2 test suite to check if accessor-columns are exported properly. All seems well, until I added an accessor following a relation, those values are not added properly to the export.</strike>

So it seems you found a bug in django-tables2, failing test in [this commit](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/commit/d9875c3fa19d86be57679e77d97e1753bc46bc60).

I'll try to come up with a fix, for next time, feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/issues/new) in the django-tables2 issue tracker at github. It really helps if you can provide a *minimal* example reproducing the issue, so please keep removing code until you are left with the bare minimum amount of code required to show the problem.

Update: ok, I should have seen this error in my tests right away: django-tables2 accessors use `.` as a separator, not `__`, which I used in my tests linked above. If I amend the test, it works like expected: [updated test](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/f67cd75bb8437d982b489e4961985c7922683c55/tests/test_export.py#L94-L111)